# Why should I use CUDA __shared__ memory as "extern"

Tags: cuda

An example how to use dynamically allocated and therefore extern `__shared__` memory in CUDA is given: [Use dynamic shared memory allocation for two different vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435559/use-dynamic-shared-memory-allocation-for-two-different-vectors)

```
    extern __shared__ float array[];
    __device__ void func()      // __device__ or __global__ function
    {
        short* array0 = (short*)array; 
        float* array1 = (float*)&array0[128];
        int*   array2 =   (int*)&array1[64];
    }
```

But why should I ever use extern dynamically allocated shared memory when I have to assign it to variables manually anyway?

I do not see any drawback to the following solution:

```
    __device__ void func()      // __device__ or __global__ function
    {
        __shared__ float array[MAXIMALLY_NEEDED_SIZE];
        short* array0 = (short*)array;
        float* array1 = (float*)&array0[128];
        int*   array2 =   (int*)&array1[64];
    }
```

Clearly, with the first solution, I can save some shared memory. But how would this ever help me?

(I guess there's a good reason for dynamically allocated memory, but I don't see it, so I probably have a lack in my understanding. That's why I ask.)

Comment: In the first code sample, the `extern` keyword means that `array` refers to shared memory declared elsewhere.  In the second code sample the absence of the `extern` keyword means that the shared memory for all references to `array` is being declared at that point.  I believe you have to use both declarations: in one place you do not use `extern` and in all other places that you use that shared memory you do.

Comment: Also, see [this link](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/) for information on why dynamic memory is always declared as `extern`.  In brief, it's because the memory is allocated to the thread block when the kernel is launched.  I.e. it's `extern` to all of your code because it's in the kernel-allocated thread block shared memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason to use dynamically allocated shared memory (as opposed to statically allocated) is similar to one reason why you might want to allocate *anything* dynamically instead of statically:  at compile-time, you don't know the size of the allocation you will want.

The example you've given doesn't illustrate this point very well.  The original purpose of that example was to illustrate how to handle multiple independent objects residing in shared memory in the dynamically allocated case, not to highlight the uses of dynamic vs. static shared memory.

> Clearly, with the first solution, I can save some shared memory. But how would this ever help me?

One possible reason that saving shared memory might be valuable, is because it can impact *occupancy*, and thus performance.

Suppose I had a parallel reduction code, and suppose that it used shared memory as the primary reduction medium.  Typically the amount of shared memory I will need will be related to the number of threads I use in my threadblock.  Now let's also suppose that depending on the exact problem I have, I may want to adjust the number of threads per threadblock, *at runtime*.

If I launch a threadblock of 256 threads, and I am doing a parallel reduction on 64-bit integers, I may need 256*8bytes (2KB) of shared memory per threadblock.  If I launch a threadblock of 1024 threads, I would need 8KB of shared memory per threadblock (this is the maximum conceivable).

If I simply hard-coded this value, so that it could be used at compile-time as part of a static allocation, I would need to use the 8KB value.  This would limit me to 6 threadblocks maximum occupancy on most GPUs (6*8KB = 48KB maximum shared memory), *even if I were launching threadblocks of only 256 threads*.  (And if I needed any shared memory for any other purpose, then my max occupancy would be less than 6 threadblocks.)

With dynamic allocation, threadblocks of 1024 threads still have the same limits as above, but threadblocks launched with 256 threads will be able to achieve theoretically higher occupancy (at least based on shared memory limits), which could translate to higher performance.

Comment: "I may want to adjust the number of threads per threadblock, at runtime." <- Ok, that's a perfect one-sentence-answer to the question, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid messy declarations such as `float* array1 = (float*)&array0[128]`, you can pack shared content in a struct:

```
struct Shared
{
    short array0[128];
    float array1[64];
    int array2[32];
};

__device__ void func()
{
    extern __shared__ Shared shr[];
    /* use example:
       shr->array0[some_index]
       shr->array1[some_index]
       shr->array2[some_index]
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another use case is code profiling/benchmarking, because the grid and dynamically allocated memory can be decided at runtime per user-supplied params, without costly recompilation.

Consider a kernel dynamically allocating shared memory

```cpp
__global__ void kernel(...) {
    extern __shared__ int sdata[];
    ...
```

launched by

```cpp
kernel<<<gridSize, blockSize, sharedBytes>>>(...)
```

where `gridSize, blockSize, sharedBytes` are arguments and can be supplied as input params.